# Are HiLog terms still useful in modern Prolog?

Tags: module, prolog, iso-prolog, meta-predicate, xsb

Are Hilog terms (i.e. compounds having as functors arbitrary terms) still regarded as a powerful feature in XSB Prolog (or any other Prolog) ?
Are there many XSB projects currently using this feature ? which of them for example ?

I ask since as far as I understand higher order programming is equally possible using the ISO built-in call/N.

Specifically, I would like to understand if XSB is using Hilog terms just for historical reasons or if Hilog terms have considerable advantages in comparison to the current ISO standard.

Comment: @bobcat: In modern Prologs, these terms are subsumed by `call/N`. So no, HiLog terms are no longer useful. Actually, they never were since `call/N` was present prior to their invention. ((It is unusual to hijack an existing question as you did here.))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within XSB, Hilog terms are very strongly connected to the module system which is unique to XSB. XSB has a functor based module system. That is, within the same scope `length(X)` might belong to one module, whereas `length(L, N)` might belong to another. As a consequence, `call(length(L), N)` might refer to one module and `call(length(L, N))` to another:

```
[Patch date: 2013/02/20 06:17:59]
| ?- use_module(basics,length/2).
yes
| ?- length(Xs,2).             
Xs = [_h201,_h203]
yes
| ?- call(length(Xs),2).
Xs = [_h217,_h219]
yes
| ?- use_module(inex,length/1). 
yes
| ?- length(Xs,2).
Xs = [_h201,_h203]
yes
| ?- call(length(Xs),2).
++Error[XSB/Runtime/P]: [Existence (No module inex exists)]  in arg 1 of predicate load
| ?- call(call(length,Xs),2).
Xs = [_h228,_h230];
```

It might be that in such a context there are differences between `call/N` and Hilog terms. I have, however, so far not found one.

Historically, Hilog terms have been introduced 1987-1989. At that point in time, `call/N` already existed as built-ins in NU and as `library(call)` in Quintus Prolog with [only cursory documentation](http://quintus.sics.se/isl/quintus/html/quintus/lib-abs.html#lib-abs). It has been proposed [1984 by Richard O'Keefe](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#plstd). On the other hand, `call/N` was clearly unknown to the authors of Hilog, as is exemplified on p.1101 of Weidong Chen, Michael Kifer, David Scott Warren: HiLog: A First-Order
Semantics for Higher-Order Logic Programming Constructs. NACLP
1989. 1090-1114. MIT-Press.

> ... Generic transitive closure can also be defined in Prolog:
>
> ```
>     closure(R, X, Y) :- C =.. [R, X, Y], call(C).
>     closure(R, X, Y) :- C =.. [R, X, Z], call(C), closure(R, Z, Y).
> ```
>
> However, this is obviously inelegant compared to HiLog (see Section 2.1), since this involves both constructing a term out of a list and reflecting this term into an atomic formula using "call". The point of this example is that the lack of theoretical foundations for higher-order constructs in Prolog resulted in an obscure syntax, which partially explains why Prolog programs involving such constructs are notoriously hard to understand.

Now, this can be done with `call/N` like so:

```
closure(R, X, Y) :- call(R, X, Y).
closure(R, X, Y) :- call(R, X, Z), closure(R, Z, Y).
```

Which is even more general than the `(=..)/2`-version because `R` is no longer restricted to being an atom. As an aside, I'd rather prefer to write:

```
closure(R_2, X0,X) :- call(R_2, X0,X1), closure0(R_2, X1,X).

closure0(_R_2, X,X).
closure0(R_2, X0,X) :- call(R_2, X0,X1), closure0(R_2, X1,X).
```

Answer (score -2):

HiLog allows goals such as

```
foo(X(a, Y(b))).
```

and ISO Prolog does not. In ISO Prolog, you'd have to write

```
foo(T), T=..[X, a, R], R=..[Y, b].
```

which is less convenient and might be slower.

Comment: In ISO Prolog you write: `foo(call(X, a, call(Y, b)))`.