# Module expansion of goals passed to library meta-predicates

Tags: module, prolog, meta-predicate

Using [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.5),
we proceed step by step:

1. Define [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) nonterminal `a//1` in module `dcgAux` (pronounced: "*di-SEE-goh*"):

   ```
   :- module(dcgAux,[a//1]).

   a(0)    --> [].
   a(s(N)) --> [a], a(N).
   ```
2. Run the following queries—using [`phrase/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase/2) and [`apply:foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4):

   ```
   ?- use_module([library(apply),dcgAux]).
   true.

   ?- phrase(      foldl(       a,[s(0),s(s(0))]),[a,a,a]).
   true.

   ?- phrase(      foldl(dcgAux:a,[s(0),s(s(0))]),[a,a,a]).
   true.

   ?- phrase(apply:foldl(dcgAux:a,[s(0),s(s(0))]),[a,a,a]).
   true.

   ?- phrase(apply:foldl(       a,[s(0),s(s(0))]),[a,a,a]).
   ERROR: apply:foldl_/4: Undefined procedure: apply:a/3
   ```

   **нет!** Quite a surprise—and not a good one. Have we been missing some unknown unknowns?
3. To get rid of above irritating behavior, we must first find out the reason(s) causing it:

   ```
   ?- import_module(apply,M), M=user.
   false.

   ?- phrase(apply:foldl(a,[s(0),s(s(0))]),[a,a,a]).
   ERROR: apply:foldl_/4: Undefined procedure: apply:a/3

   ?- add_import_module(apply,user,end).
   true.

   ?- import_module(apply,M), M=user.   % sic!
   M = user.                            % `?- import_module(apply,user).` fails!

   ?- phrase(apply:foldl(a,[s(0),s(s(0))]),[a,a,a]).
   true.
   ```

---

**What's going on?** The way I see it is this:

- Module expansion of the goal passed to `foldl/4` is limited.
- Quoting from the [SWI-Prolog manual page on `import_module/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=import_module/2):

  > All normal modules only import from user, which imports from system.
- SWI's `library(apply)` only "inherits" from `system`, but not `user`.
- If we clone module `apply` to `applY` (and propagate the new module name), we observe:

  ```
  ?- use_module(applY).
  true.

  ?- phrase(applY:foldl(a,[s(0),s(s(0))]),[a,a,a]).  % was: ERROR
  true.                                              % now: OK!
  ```

Please share your ideas on how I could/should proceed!

(I have not yet run a similar experiment with other Prolog processors.)

Comment: @false. How clumsy! I was misled by the sloppy (too colloquial) uses of "standard" by others, most notably http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/stdlib.html . Thanks for noticing! Should be better now!

Comment: @false. In general, English is notoriously prone to ambiguity ( just look at http://www.dict.cc/?s=standardo ). I have seen theoretical math guys use "standard" / "non-standard" in peculiar ways. And, what about the word "**norm**al"?

Comment: @false. "Vendor-supplied" is **not** the right phrase. I get that, but I'd rather use a better phrase than none. Why? With SWI, `library(apply)` and `applY` behave differently if `add_import_module/3` is not used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an inherent feature/bug of predicate based module systems in the Quintus tradition. That is, this module system was first developed for Quintus Prolog. It was adopted subsequently by SICStus (after 0.7<sup>1</sup>), then (more or less) by 13211-2, then by YAP, and (with some modifications) by SWI.

The problem here is what exactly an explicit qualification means. As long as the goal is no meta-predicate, things are trivially resolvable: Take the module of the innermost qualification. However, once you have meta-predicates, the meta-arguments need to be informed of that module ; or not. If the meta-arguments are informed, we say that *the colon sets the calling context*, if not, then some other means is needed for that purpose.

In Quintus tradition, the meta-arguments are taken into account. With the result you see. As a consequence you cannot compare two implementations of the same meta-predicate in the same module directly. There are other approaches most notably [IF](http://www.ifcomputer.de) and [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/) that do not change the calling context via the colon. This has advantages and disadvantages. The best is to compare them case by case.

Here is a recent case. Take [lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord#implementation) and how they are put into a module
in SICStus, [in SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl), and [in ECLiPSe](http://www.eclipseclp.org/docs/Dev/current/bips/lib_public/lambda/index.html).

As for the Quintus/SICStus/YAP/SWI module system, I'd rather use it in the most conservative manner possible. That is:

- no explicit qualification, consider the infix `:` as something internal
- clean, checkable meta-declarations - insert on purpose an undefined predicate just to see whether or not cross-referencing is able to detect the problem (in SWI that's `check` or `make`).
- use the common subset, avoid the many bells and whistles - there are many well meant extensions...
- do more versatile things the pedestrian way: reexport by adding an appropriate module and add a dummy definition. Similarly, instead of renaming, import things from an interface module.
- be always aware that module systems have **inherently** some limits. No matter how you twist or turn it. There is no completely seamless module system, for the very purpose of modules is to separate code and concerns.

---

1: To be precise, SICStus' adaptation of Quintus modules did only include `:` for module sensitive arguments in `meta_predicate` declarations. The integers `0..9`, which are so important for higher-order programming based on `call/N` were only introduced about 20 years later in
[4.2.0 released 2011-03-08](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.2.0/html/relnotes/4_002e2_002e0-New-Features.html).

Comment: Up to now my experience with Prolog module system(s) has been modest at best. Very, that is. Your answer rings true. I appreciate pieces of advise and/or hints on "best practices"!

Comment: I was on the fence and weighing pros and cons of explicit quantification, particularly for (small) code snippets---not so much for bigger projects (which ideally start with a consensus on arch/design/layout/etc). How about that `?- [user]. somecode.^D` in combination with explicit qualification like `user:a`?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15483764/772868) is a problem with functor based modules.