# What are the (perceived) shortcomings of the ISO standard for Prolog modules (ISO/IEC 13211-2)?

Tags: module, prolog, iso-prolog

The ISO standard for Prolog modules is not widely adopted.  The only system I found that seems to implement them is [Amzi! Prolog](https://github.com/AmziLS/AmziProlog).  What is the reason that most systems haven't adopted the ISO standard for modules?  I can find statements that this is due to shortcomings of the specification, but I haven't been able to find evidence to back up these statements.  What problems do other module systems solve that aren't solved by the ISO standard for Prolog modules?  Wouldn't it be helpful for the Prolog community if systems at least offered ISO Prolog modules as a common denominator?

There are already a few questions on StackOverflow on the ISO standard for Prolog modules, but they do not answer the above questions.  As StackOverflow is not the place to discuss opinions, I am more interested in:

**What are the technical merits and shortcomings of the ISO standard for Prolog modules compared with other implemented module systems?**

Comment: It would be nice if the yet silent downvoters could explain why they downvoted the question (and what action would make them reconsider the downvote).

Comment: This question probably doesn't meet usual Question criteria (e.g. focus, opinion-based, single question). Is there a public URL to the standard? I suggest asking at e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/ and https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/

Comment: @brebs Thanks. I am definitely interested in fact-based replies, not in opinions (which I can find plentily). Following your comment, I highlighted the central question to make the focus clear.

Comment: This is in fact a good question if you wanted to start a flame war on several fronts simultaneously :-D this is not your fault at all. If I were you, and _really_ **really** wanted to know, I would contact a few of the authors/contributors to the standard as well as the maintainers of a few of the Prolog implementations and ask them about this. You will get opinions which you can use to form your own opinion.

Comment: People who are looking for a flame war should look somewhere else. :) I followed the advice on Ulrich Neumerkel's ISO Prolog page, where he encourages asking questions about the standard publicly, especially here on SO. I wonder why it can be so hard to list merits as well as unresolved issues with the standard. I do not know enough to be able to answer the question myself. From looking at the ISO standard for Prolog modules, I don't see an obvious problem that would make its implementation or use unfeasible. I don't want to discuss the relevance of standards.

Comment: OK, great, so you got **one opinion**. You will find a _strict subset_ of people here on SO, just so that you know.

Comment: @Marc: Answering your question takes time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module standard ISO/IEC 13211-2:2000 permits several realizations. The document itself gives two instances in 6.4.4.1 and 6.4.4.2. This is one of the bigger problems for its adoption. In fact, even the Quintus/SICStus based module system could be seen as a further instance.

Another (minor) problem is the poor support of higher-order predicates having only one kind of meta-arguments regardless of their precise meaning. But, to be fair, this was not yet well understood in 2000 by many. While this mechanism was provided by Quintus since at least 1986-04, many key features were very well hidden in the manual like `call/N` which was never listed in the [predicate index](https://quintus.sics.se/isl/quintus/html/quintus/pindex.html#pindex). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32144795/772868) for more.

As to the system you are referring to, I cursorily checked the [source](https://github.com/AmziLS/AmziProlog) which self declares compliance. On the other hand, it does not seem to be based fully on Part 1 (13211-1). E.g., there is a built-in `sub_atom/4` but the standard has `sub_atom/5`. And the throwing of errors does not seem to be conforming.  So I am somewhat hesitant to investigate this any further as I cannot compile the system. Many systems claimed compliance/conformance but a closer investigation often shows unsatisfactory results.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the link to your 2015 answer for Quintus-style module systems.  A fully satisfactory module system would probably have to take the lessons learned in Scheme (https://www.r6rs.org/final/r6rs.pdf) into account, but this means that predicate names (corresponding to identifiers in Scheme) would no longer have a canonical representation as identifiers (corresponding to symbol datums in Scheme).

Comment: We had these discussions in the 1980s. In fact, the first module systems were name based (so there is a 1-to-1 correspondence of atoms/functors and predicates) and **not** predicate based as ISO/IF/Quintus is. And some tried to be "in between" like [XSB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483764/772868) with quite questionable side effects.